# Filtering Pandas Dataframe for even or odd int values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to filter a data frame if the column contains even or odd values. For example I would like this table:

| Player | Score |
| --- | --- |
| A | 15 |
| B | 14 |
| C | 12 |

To look like this when filtering for Score even values:

| Player | Score |
| --- | --- |
| B | 14 |
| C | 12 |

My working solution is to create a new column using the modulo operator (%) to divide the values by 2 and then filter if it is a 1 or 0.

```
df['even_odd'] = df.Score % 2
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: `df[df.Score % 2==0]`.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? `df.loc[df['Score'].mod(2).eq(0)]`

Comment: Excellent! Seems so obvious now :)